# NPM node-v: COMMAND NOT FOUND

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, git-bash

```
node -v
npm -v
live-server
```

Whenever i run these commands (there maybe others I don't know of) bash returns error. I use Bash as the default terminal of VS Code for my local dev environment. The strange thing is that when i try to run `npm -v` or `node-v` outside the integrated bash terminal of VS Code and directly into an independent Bash terminal it shows the result (the version). But the same wont work in the VSC integrated terminal and returns `command not found`. These strange things started happening just recently. Before that it was all fine.

Comment: Are you running `node-v` or `node -v` (with the space)?

Comment: I use the space... However tried both,,,, The problem is only there for bash